# copy a string form a line and paste at the end in another line for a huge file based on pattern

Tags: string, sed, grep, pattern-matching, paste

I have the below requirement. I am trying to run the condition in loop and it's taking more time. Is there a one time command anything which will not take more time to process a 70 MB file.

Requirement:
if @pRECTYPE="SBSB" line contains @pSBEL_MCTR_RSN="XXX" tag then we need to copy and append that to next @pRECTYPE="SBEL record at the end  of the line

File :note : in file there will be no blank lines. I have given enter to avoid line continuation

```
@pRUKE=dfgt@pRECTYPE="SMDR", @pCONFIG="Y" XXXXXXX

@pRUKE=dfgt@pRECTYPE="SBSB", @pGWID="1234",  @pSBEL_MCTR_RSN="KX28", @pSBSB_9000_COLL=""

@pRUKE=dfgt@pRECTYPE="KBSG", @pKBSG_UPDATE_CD="IN", XXXXXXXXXXX

@pRUKE=dfgt@pRECTYPE="SBEL", @pSBEL_EFF_DT="01/01/2017",  @pCSPI_ID="JKOX0001", @pSBEL_FI="A"

@pRUKE=dfgt@pRECTYPE="SBEK", @pSBEK_UPDATE_CD="IN",XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

@pRUKE=dfgt@pRECTYPE="DBCS", @pDBCS_UPDATE_CD="IN",XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

@pRUKE=dfgt@pRECTYPE="MEME", @pMEME_REL="18",  @pMEEL_MCTR_RSN="KX28"

@pRUKE=dfgt@pRECTYPE="ATT0", @pATT0_UPDATE_CD="AP",XXXXXXXXX

@pRUKE=dfgt@pRECTYPE="SBSB", @pGWID="1234",  @pSBEL_MCTR_RSN="KX28", @pSBSB_9000_COLL=""

@pRUKE=dfgt@pRECTYPE="KBSG", @pKBSG_UPDATE_CD="IN", XXXXXXXXXXX
```

example :

Before :

```
@pRUKE=dfgt@pRECTYPE="SMDR", @pCONFIG="Y" XXXXXXX

@pRUKE=dfgt@pRECTYPE="SBSB", @pGWID="1234",  @pSBEL_MCTR_RSN="KX28", @pSBSB_9000_COLL=""

@pRUKE=dfgt@pRECTYPE="KBSG", @pKBSG_UPDATE_CD="IN", XXXXXXXXXXX

@pRUKE=dfgt@pRECTYPE="SBEL", @pSBEL_EFF_DT="01/01/2017",  @pCSPI_ID="JKOX0001", @pSBEL_FI="A"
```

After:

```
@pRUKE=dfgt@pRECTYPE="SMDR", @pCONFIG="Y" XXXXXXX

@pRUKE=dfgt@pRECTYPE="SBSB", @pGWID="1234", @pSBEL_MCTR_RSN="KX28", @pSBSB_9000_COLL=""

@pRUKE=dfgt@pRECTYPE="KBSG", @pKBSG_UPDATE_CD="IN", XXXXXXXXXXX

@pRUKE=dfgt@pRECTYPE="SBEL", @pSBEL_EFF_DT="01/01/2017",  @pCSPI_ID="JKOX0001", @pSBEL_FI="A", @pSBEL_MCTR_RSN="KX28"
```

After SBSB, if there is no SBEL, then that SBSB can be ignored.

What I did is:

```
egrep -n "pRECTYPE=\"SBSB\"|pRECTYPE=\"SBEL\""  filename | sed '$!N;/pRECTYPE=\"SBEL\"/P;D' |  awk -F\: '{print $1}'  |  awk 'NR%2{printf "%s,",$0;next;}1' > 4.txt;
```

by this I will get the line number, eg:

```
2,4
17,19
```

Line 9 12 14 will be ignored

```
while read line 
 do

     echo "$line";
     SBSB=`echo  "$line" | awk -F, '{print $1}'`;
     SBEL=`echo  "$line" | awk -F, '{print $2}'`;
    echo $SBSB;
    echo $SBEL;
     SBSB_Fetch=`sed -n "$SBSB p" $fil | grep -Eo '(@pSBEL_MCTR_RSN)=[^ ]+'  | sed 's/,$//' | sed 's/^/, /g'`;
     echo $SBSB_Fetch;
        if [[ "$SBSB_Fetch" == "" ]];then
            echo "blank";
            s=blank;
        else
            echo "value";
            sed -i "${SBEL}s/.*/&${SBSB_Fetch}/" $fil;
         fi

done < 4.txt;
```

Since I am ready and updating each line ,it's taking more time, is there any way to reduce the run time?
For 70 Mb it's taking 4 .5 hours now.

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performance, you need to really limit how many external tools you invoke inside a loop in a shell script.

This requires GNU awk:

```sh
gawk '
  /@pRECTYPE="SBSB"/ {match($0, /@pSBEL_MCTR_RSN="[^"]*"/, m)}
  /@pRECTYPE="SBEL"/ && isarray(m) {$0 = $0 ", " m[0]; delete m}
  1
' file
```

This should be pretty quick:

- only invoking one external command
- no shell loops
- only have to read the input file once.

Comment: it working but while pasting its pasting by inserting as a new line, can you provide a command which will print in the end of the line

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean that the @pSBEL_MCTR_RSN bit is showing up as a separate line? Are you setting gawk's OFS variable to newline?